# generate random number in matlab_p probability to get 1 and (1-p) probability to get -1

Tags: matlab

Now I want to generate Bernoulli random numbers in matlab. However, if I use standard Bernoulli Distribution function, the default value is 0 and 1. 
  Now I want to generate a random number with p probability to get 1 and (1-p) probability to get -1. How to deal with it in Matlab?

Comment: You need a linear scaling of a variable: `r2 = (r1 - 0.5) * 2`. Where `r1` is the Bernoulli random number.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve] detailing your code. Explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.

Answer (score 0):

rand() gives a random number uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.

if you wrote rand(1) + p, where 0<=p<=1, then p % of value would be greater than 1.  Flooring this result will give p chance of 1 and (1-p) chance of getting 0.  Multiply by 2 and subtract 1 to get to -1 and +1;

```
rand_bern = floor(rand(n) + p) * 2 - 1;
```